# Verify addition of wear activity in existing eclipse project

Tags: android

I just started adding wear support to existing eclipse project. The steps I have done till now:

1) Add a new acivity which uses a layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/yt.ty"
    android:id="@+id/watch_view_stub"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:rectLayout="@layout/activityrect"
    app:roundLayout="@layout/activityround" >

</android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub>
```

The activityrect.xml and activityround xml files are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World_RectangeScreen" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In my activity I am right now just displaying a Toast message.
My question is how will this wear activity run on wear. I already have a MainActivity with intent "android.intent.action.MAIN" for running on phones and tablets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have to setup wear project in eclipse.
   Like it described here http://blog.benjamin-cabe.com/2014/07/04/how-to-setup-eclipse-for-android-wear-development
   To be honest it would be much easier to develop in Android Studio, but it's up to you anyway.
2. If you want to see you you wear app on your wear device, you need to pack you wear project (or build mobile containing wear with the release keys).
   Then you can install it via IDE or adb instal your.package.wear
3. If already done previous steps and wants to open wear app from mobile app, then you need to send message to wear

Mobile part:

> private void sendStartActivityMessage(String node) {
>
> ```
>     Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(
>             mGoogleApiClient, node, START_ACTIVITY_PATH, new byte[0]).setResultCallback(
>             new ResultCallback<SendMessageResult>() {
>                 @Override
>                 public void onResult(SendMessageResult sendMessageResult) {
>                     if (!sendMessageResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
>                         Log.e(TAG, "Failed to send message with status code: "
>                                 + sendMessageResult.getStatus().getStatusCode());
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
>     );
> }
> ```

Wear part:

> public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent) {
>
> ```
>     if (messageEvent.getPath().equals(START_ACTIVITY_PATH)) {
>         Intent startIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivityWear.class);
>         startIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
>         startActivity(startIntent);
>     }
>   }
> ```

Check this https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/messages.html
and DalaLayer project in wear sample projects.